# How to list available tenants in ABP Framework Angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, abp

I wish to list the available tenants on my homepage (on an ABP Framework generated Angular app). Each item in the list should have a link to that tenant.

First problem is I cannot find the service that is supposed to return the tenants: I tried `AbpTenantService` and `MultiTenancyService`.

There is an endpoint (`GET /api/multi-tenancy/tenants`) generated on the ASP.NET Core host, but I cannot seem to find the proxy in TypeScript.

I did make sure to run `abp generate-proxy`.

The ancillary issue is that passing `__tenant={tenant_name}` or `__tenant={tenant_id}`  to the query string does not seem to work to change the tenant.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy#default-tenant-resolvers) the default template includes the query string tenant resolver: `QueryStringTenantResolveContributor`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get get tenants (from host side)

```
public class GetTenantsInput : PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto
    {
        public string Filter { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
 public class SaasTenantDto : ExtensibleEntityDto<Guid>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
public class EfCoreTenantRepository : EfCoreRepository<ISaasDbContext, Tenant, Guid>, ITenantRepository
{
    public EfCoreTenantRepository(IDbContextProvider<ISaasDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {

    } 

    public virtual async Task<List<Tenant>> GetListAsync(
        string sorting = null,
        int maxResultCount = int.MaxValue,
        int skipCount = 0,
        string filter = null,
        bool includeDetails = false,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await (await GetDbSetAsync())
            .IncludeDetails(includeDetails)
            .WhereIf(
                !filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                u =>
                    u.Name.Contains(filter)
            )
            .OrderBy(sorting ?? nameof(Tenant.Name))
            .PageBy(skipCount, maxResultCount)
            .ToListAsync(GetCancellationToken(cancellationToken));
    }

    public virtual async Task<long> GetCountAsync(string filter = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await this
            .WhereIf(
                !filter.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                u =>
                    u.Name.Contains(filter)
            ).CountAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }

    [Obsolete("Use WithDetailsAsync method.")]
    public override IQueryable<Tenant> WithDetails()
    {
        return GetQueryable().IncludeDetails();
    }

    public override async Task<IQueryable<Tenant>> WithDetailsAsync()
    {
        return (await GetQueryableAsync()).IncludeDetails();
    }
}
```

---

```
public virtual async Task<PagedResultDto<SaasTenantDto>> GetListAsync(GetTenantsInput input)
{
    var count = await TenantRepository.GetCountAsync(input.Filter);
    var list = await TenantRepository.GetListAsync(
        input.Sorting,
        input.MaxResultCount,
        input.SkipCount,
        input.Filter
    );

    var tenantDtos = ObjectMapper.Map<List<Tenant>, List<SaasTenantDto>>(list);

    return new PagedResultDto<SaasTenantDto>(
        count,
        tenantDtos
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try it out.Is there any reason not to use the functions on IIdentityUserRepository?

Comment: there's no tenant specific logic inside the IIdentityUserRepository. as you may know, it's only related with user.

Comment: Sorry Alper, I got mixed up replying to a different answer. I'm going to implement your suggestion tonight. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Alper, sorry it seems your solution only applies to ABP Commercial. Thanks nonetheless.